# Xamarin Forms Grid IsVisbile binding only works in one way

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I noticed a strange behavior with my XAML page.
This is my PageContent. I'm running the app in the iOS Simulator.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanReverseVisibilityConverter}}">
            <!-- Main content -->
        </Grid>

        <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
            <!-- Busy indicator -->
            <Label Text="Doing some stuff..."/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I have my main content in the upper grid. While page is doing stuff, the main grid should be invisible and the busy grid schould become visible.

For know, only the main content becomes invisible, however the busy grid stays invisible as well.

This is my binding property.

```
private bool _isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => _isBusy;
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy == value) return;
                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

I do set the `IsBusy` variable in an `AsyncCommand` (also tried a normal `Command`). The example is shown below.

Command

```
CalculateCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () => await CalculateAction(), (t) => 
CalculateCommand_CanExcecute(t));
```

Task

```
private async Task CalculateAction()
        {
            IsBusy= true;
            try
            {
                IncrementalNumber++;
                //Do some calculation

                await ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(string.Format("{0}?cid={1}", ShellRoute.CalculationResultPage.ToString(), culc.Id), false);
                IsCalculating = false;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                    Strings.DialogUnexpectedErrorOccurredHeadline,
                    string.Format(Strings.DialogUnexpectedErrorOccurredFormatedContent, exc.Message),
                    Strings.Close
                    );

                IsBusy= false;

            }
        }
```

I guess it has something to do with the thread. I tried to invoke the `IsBusy` property in the main thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    {
                        IsBusy = true;
                    }
                });
```

This seems to work, however this takes a while. The calculation is almost done until the invoke sets the visual UI to the current state.
I'm kind of lost here.
Thanks!

Comment: The code you provided does not mentioned that how to binding with `CalculateCommand `. What does the "binding only works in one way" mean?

Comment: Hi, the CalculateCommand is binded to a button. Once I click the button, the main grid becomes invisible. That works, however the currently invisible "Busy Grid" will not be set to visible. Both grids are binded to the "IsBusy" bool property. So in other words, the binding works to set the main grid invisible, however not to set the busy grid visible. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I seemed to be a bug in Visual Studio. I just cut (ctrl + x) and paste the whole XAML code again. Since that, it's working as expected. No code changes.. strange, but glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

try use a trigger.

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid IsVisible="false">
        <Label Text="MainContent"/>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference IsBusyGrid}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>

    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
          x:Name="IsBusyGrid">
        <!-- Busy indicator -->
        <Label Text="Doing some stuff..."/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I already have tried to do it with ´DataTrigger´. Haven't work either for me. I guess it has something to do with the ´Task`. I seems to work when I set the IsBusy property on the main thread, however delayed...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem was in `bool _isBusy` property, missing `{get; set;}`

```
bool _isBusy // not working

bool _isBusy {get; set;} // solved
```